# Pass boolean to php file on form submission based on aria-checked="true" or "false" - with a button type="button" and role="switch"

Tags: php, html

I have this switch toggle element and I could not find some example of how I can determine the current value (true/false) during a form submission. I know there are related questions but nothing that exactly focuses on this part.

Please forgive me if this does not work and the question is bad.

I would like to add the value to a php script for further actions. I know that I could also change to checkboxes but than I would have to create a new design and atm I have got many of those switches.

my `html`:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/alpinejs" defer></script>

<div class="flex items-start">
  <div class="flex-shrink-0">
    <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-mixed-one bg-mixed-one"
      x-data="{ on: false }" role="switch" aria-checked="true" :aria-checked="on.toString()" @click="on = !on" x-state:on="Enabled" x-state:off="Not Enabled" :class="{ 'bg-mixed-one': on, 'bg-gray-300': !(on) }">

         <span class="sr-only">Policy</span>
           <span aria-hidden="true" 
             class="inline-block h-5 w-5 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200 translate-x-5" 
             x-state:on="Enabled" 
             x-state:off="Not Enabled" 
             :class="{ 'translate-x-5': on, 'translate-x-0': !(on) }">
            </span>
     </button>
  </div>
  <div class="ml-3">
    <p class="text-base text-gray-500">* Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: There's no form, how is anytihng being sent to PHP?

Comment: You need to do it in JavaScript. It can add a hidden input to the form and put the state of the button.